# Files missing warning after upgrading to Xcode 8 and converting syntax from swift 2.3 to swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, swift3, xcode8

I upgraded from `Xcode 7.3` to `Xcode 8.0` and changed syntax from `swift 2.3 to swift 3.0`. I am able to build the project and run fine but I got some 233 warnings all about images I used in `Assets.xcassets.`

I realized that the path is wrong as I changed the name of my project from `projectA to projectB` and the path is referring to an invalid path which is

```
/Users/name/Desktop/projectA/projectB/Assets.xcassets/Images/img_01.imageset/img_01@2x.png is missing from working copy
```

I believe that I have to remove name of those files from my `sourcecontrol` as they are not valid anymore. I have committed all my changes and have no idea how to remove these missing file links to get rid of those warnings.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was able to solve this after a lot of research.

I went to `projectB.xcodeproject > Show package contents > project.pbxproj > xcuserdata`. Delete the xcuserdata.

Then go to `Source Control > Commit`
Commit all changes. Since the path doesn't exist, Xcode will not commit changes; so just cancel out of it and do

```
Source Control > Refresh Status
```

Then exit out of Xcode and restart it.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that worked for me was to open the **.xcodeproj** and then **Option key (on keyboard) + (Product (top menu) -> Clean Build Folder)**

Note. Even if you are using cocoapods and usually open the project with .xcworkspace, you still need to perform above with .xcodeproj

Comment: This worked well for me. Also, I had no idea you could hold option to expose more items under the main menu. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Start terminal, go to the project directory, call:

```
git commit -a -m "some hints"
```

After restarting XCode the message should be gone. I think XCode is calling `git commit` without `-a` option

Answer (score 1):

In your XCode Projects Folder write "git add ." and then commit it. If you have erased some project you should use "git add -u ." and then commit it again.
This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CocoaPods, you might need to do what learner122 said in your projects Pods directory, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same as above poster, but I didn't have to delete the XCuserdata file:

1. Commit dialogue
2. Manually selected the missing/unrecognized Swift file
3. clicked Commit files
4. and "Refresh Status"

the error message disappeared. All good.